# How to query database for last radio button selected?

Tags: jquery, database, radio-button, selected

I need to know how to query the database for the last radio button selected by user so when they refresh the page or login on a different session, they will see their selection. I'm using jquery.min.js (1.7.1) for the show/hide functionality.

**Here is the HTML:**

```
    <div class="wrap">
    <div class="box">
      <div align=center id="catNav">
<label> &nbsp; <input type="radio" name="group_name" id="list-one-button" value="01" checked="checked" /></label>
<label> &nbsp; <input type="radio" name="group_name" id="list-two-button" value="02" /></label>
<label> &nbsp; <input type="radio" name="group_name" id="list-three-button" value="03" /></label>
<label> &nbsp; <input type="radio" name="group_name" id="list-four-button" value="04" /></label>
<label> &nbsp; <input type="radio" name="group_name" id="list-five-button" value="05" /></label>
<label> &nbsp; <input type="radio" name="group_name" id="list-six-button" value="06" /></label>
<label> &nbsp; <input type="radio" name="group_name" id="list-seven-button" value="07" /></label>
      </div>

      <ul class="cat-list" id="list-one">
<li><a href="#"><img src="img1.jpg"></a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="cat-list" id="list-two">
<li><a href="#"><img src="img2.jpg"></a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="cat-list" id="list-three">
<li><a href="#"><img src="img3.jpg"></a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="cat-list" id="list-four">
<li><a href="#"><img src="img4.jpg"></a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="cat-list" id="list-five">
<li><a href="#"><img src="img5.jpg"></a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="cat-list" id="list-six">
<li><a href="#"><img src="img6.jpg"></a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="cat-list" id="list-seven">
<li><a href="#"><img src="img3.jpg"></a></li>
      </ul>         
    </div>
</div>
```

**and here is the Javascript:**

```
$(function(){
$("#list-two").hide();  
$("#list-three").hide();    
$("#list-four").hide();
$("#list-five").hide();
$("#list-six").hide();
$("#list-seven").hide();

$("#list-one-button").click(function(){
    $(".cat-list").slideUp(600);
    $("#list-one").slideDown(600);
});

$("#list-two-button").click(function(){
    $(".cat-list").slideUp(600);
    $("#list-two").slideDown(600);
}); 

$("#list-three-button").click(function(){
    $(".cat-list").slideUp(600);
    $("#list-three").slideDown(600);
}); 

$("#list-four-button").click(function(){
    $(".cat-list").slideUp(600);
    $("#list-four").slideDown(600);
});

$("#list-five-button").click(function(){
    $(".cat-list").slideUp(600);
    $("#list-five").slideDown(600);
});

$("#list-six-button").click(function(){
    $(".cat-list").slideUp(600);
    $("#list-six").slideDown(600);
});

$("#list-seven-button").click(function(){
    $(".cat-list").slideUp(600);
    $("#list-seven").slideDown(600);
});

$("#catNav li a").click(function() {
    $("#catNav li").removeClass("activeCatButton");
    $(this).parent().addClass("activeCatButton");
});
});
```

Comment: JavaScript/jQuery are client-side (executed in the browser), whereas a database is server-side (stored on the web server). You need to tell us which language you use on the server and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I am only a web designer (html/css) with a purchased member site in PHP. I know very little about javascript or PHP... just enough to patch pages together :( If it is explained succinctly enough, I've worked a little with PHP and javascript... enough to enable me to make it work. Thanks much... oh, and here is a working non-dynamic example (without the selected button being remembered: [link](http://autoprospector.com/radio/)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired effect by utilizing AJAX calls.

Here is the jQuery part:

```
$('ul.cat-list').click(function() {
  var id = this.prop('id');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "saveSelection.php",
    data: "id=" + id,
  }).done(function( msg ) {
    // this is just for debugging purposes
    // console.log("Data Saved: " + msg);
  });
});
```

In PHP you can save the value. This could be the file `saveSelection.php`:

```
<?php
  // save in session
  $_SESSION['selection'] = $_POST['id'];
  // or save in database, for example by storing the user's ip address or login id
  ...
?>
```

Then, if the user requests the page again, check if there is a presaved value, and render the radio button as selected.

By the way, you are using lists wrongly. Correct would be one `ul` tag with multiple `li` tags:

```
<ul class="cat-list" id="list">
    <li id="item-one"><a href="#"><img src="img1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li id="item-two"><a href="#"><img src="img2.jpg"></a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Alp. Because the way the above javascript is written for the sliding show/hide action, I had to insert class and id inside the <li> tags after reconstructing the list as suggested, ie `<li class="cat-list" id="list">`

This, I assume, required me to change line 1 in your jQuery script from `ul.cat-list` to `li.cat-list`. But after inserting both the script and creating the suggested PHP file, the radio button still returns to the #1 button, with the #1 image.

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with the show/hide code in the original javascript above where:

`$("#list-two").hide();  
$("#list-three").hide();    
$("#list-four").hide();
$("#list-five").hide();
$("#list-six").hide();
$("#list-seven").hide();`